# SQL Select based on position of columns. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a mySQL database and I wondered if I could select columns, not by their names, but instead by their position in table.
Let's think I have a table (mixed english and french data) with the following columns:

```
id
en_name
en_phone
en_address
fr_name
fr_phone
fr_address
```

But this is just for demonstration purpose and my real table has 20 English and 20 French columns.
Is it possible to select all English or all French columns without listing their name in `SELECT`?
**WHAT IS THE BEST PRACTICE IF THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE?**

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do - but you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am trying to have a multilingual website and I want to have records with 2 languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using standard SQL, the answer is no.  There is no construct like:

```
select fr_*
```

to get all the columns that start with `fr_`.

You can use dynamic SQL (prepared statements) to generate the SQL that you want.  You can use a view to select only the English or French columns.  You could store the data so the columns are on different rows and you have a language identifier, used in a select.  In some databases, you can use a stored procedure to return only the columns that you want.

But, using just a SQL query, you don't have that flexibility.

EDIT:

You can create a view like:

```
create view table_fr as
     select id, fr_name, fr_phone, fr_address
     from t;
```

The best practice, though, would be to have a table that stores language as a separate column:

```
id
Language
Name
Phone
Address
```

And to split the data for a single `id` into multiple rows, one for each language.  You might have *another* table for language independent information about the id.

Comment: Thanks! I understand I can put a language column and store each row on two rows and do not like to do that because It will cause complications. but I didnt understand the other solutions, like using view. please explain.

Comment: Thanks many times, but I didnt get the last point. `And to split data...`. Would you please shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

(this answer was originally written by [Mark Bannister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359040/mark-bannister), but he deleted it. I don't know why - it was good advice)

The best practice would be to normalize your table - so the structure as given would become:

```
id
language
name
phone
address
```

You could then get a listing of values for a specific language by running a query like:

```
select * from myTable
where language = 'en';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philipp, but splitting columns to multiple rows is not called normalization. to normalize you should create more tables, not rows.